# How to test a Spring Boot REST API with multiple parallel requests

Tags: java, spring-boot, mocking, integration-testing, spring-restcontroller

I am writing integration tests for a REST API. I would like to test the application with multiple parallel requests. Can I do it programmatically?

Below is my Test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class,MockitoExtension.class})
@SpringBootTest
@ActivePRofiles("test")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyConfiguration.class)
public class MyControllerTest {
    @Resource(name = "products")
    public Map<String,String> products;

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    WebAplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Mock
    SomeService someService;
    ...
    ...
    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        ...
        ...
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();
        ...
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK.value(),result.getResponse().getStatus());
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Did you considered using CompletableFuture API ?